# Python: Creating a "ghost image"

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Is there a way to modify images to make a "ghost" of an image and adding it back into the original (as shown below) using image processing? By ghosted I specifically mean creating a copy of the original image, and adding it back in with increased transparency shifted slightly. I tried using openCV's `addWeighted` function in a variety of color spaces (RGB, HSV, ...), and the images never looked correct (mainly due to colors shifting)

[image: original image] [image: ghosted image]

================================================================
Edit: 2022-10-16 21:15
When I am using OpenCV to combine images I produce the image below. The desired output is the image to the right above (produced via matplotlib)

[image: openCV]

```
import cv2

def shift_image(img, dx=0, dy=0):
        M = np.float32([[1, 0, dx], [0, 1, dy]])
        return cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

img = cv2.imread('image/0.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
mask = 255 * (~((img == 0).all(axis=2))).astype(np.uint8)

masked_img = cv2.merge([*(cv2.split(img)), mask],4)

shifted_img = shift_image(masked_img, 5, -2)
merged_img = cv2.addWeighted(masked_img, 1, shifted_img, 0.5, 0)

mask = merged_img[:,:,-1] == 0
merged_img[mask, :3] = 0
merged_img[mask, -1] = 255

cv2.imwrite("test.png", merged_img)
```

Comment: To prevent color shifting you need to blend images with a linear color space rather than the gamma corrected one that's the default.

Comment: @MarkRansom - I'm not sure what that means. Could you give me a bit more detail? Is are there specific color space?

Comment: [mre] please. how did you make that picture? is that picture what you want, or is that _not_ what you want? what do you want instead? precise details...

Comment: splicing an alpha channel into your pictures won't do anything on the level of OpenCV. nor will setting `mask` to 0 (!!!) because now you've got an *integer index* in your attempted *mask indexing* operations. -- scrap the entire code. rebuild line by line. inspect the effects of every single step you do. work in an interactive python session. look at the values of your inputs and outputs

Comment: When I export and look at the images on a background the alpha channel does make a difference. Any advice on preserving color in the image?

Comment: please don't just ignore the majority of my comment. -- *yes* OpenCV can save 4-channel images. if you prepare the data properly, it'll even make sense. still, OpenCV does not see the 4th channel as special.